# cloud sql connection error (OperationalError)

Tags: django, sockets, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-sql

I am getting following error after uploading the application on google app engine.
But on my local machine everything is working fine

```
OperationalError at /users/

(2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)")

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://arctic-anvil-728.appspot.com/users/
Django Version:     1.4.13
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

(2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)")

Exception Location:     /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__, line 190
Python Executable:  /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['/base/data/home/apps/s~arctic-anvil-728/1.379355097665075133',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']

Server time:    Mon, 13 Oct 2014 13:45:19 +0000
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Connect_to_your_database). You should be using unix_socket when connecting from App Engine.

Comment: I have shared my settings.py, plz have a look

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tony for your answer, Yes i have read the documentation but no luck :(
I am using Django rest framework with google app engine
Please look into my "settings.py" files:

```
"""

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*****************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my-rest.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my-rest.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'INSTANCE': 'appid:sql_instance_id',
        'NAME': '********',
        'USER': '********',
        'HOST': '***.**.**.**',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
    }
}

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
#        'NAME': 'app_engine',
#        'USER': 'root',
#        'HOST': 'localhost',
#        'PASSWORD': ''
#    }
#}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If somebody wants my sample code than i can provide it.
Please tell me what is the wrong with the this code.

Comment: According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/, django will assume it's unix socket when the host value starts with a slash. Can you try to use '/cloudsql/<your project:your db>' for the host value?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal (assume you have gcloud installed):

1. gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
2. API [sqladmin.googleapis.com] not enabled on project ...
3. Yes, enable

Try to connect

Docs:
Before you begin

> If you're new to Google Cloud, create an account to evaluate how our
> products perform in real-world scenarios. New customers get $300 in
> free credits to run, test, and deploy workloads. In the Google Cloud
> console, on the project selector page, select or create a Google Cloud
> project.
>
> Note: If you don't plan to keep the resources that you create in this
> procedure, create a project instead of selecting an existing project.
> After you finish these steps, you can delete the project, removing all
> resources associated with the project. Go to project selector
>
> Make sure that billing is enabled for your Cloud project. Learn how to
> check if billing is enabled on a project.
>
> **Enable the Cloud SQL Admin API**, Secret Manager, and Cloud Build APIs.